# Hadoop cache file for all map tasks

Tags: java, file-io, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-cache

My map function has to read a file for every input. That file doesn't change at all, it is only for reading. Distributed cache might help me a lot i think, but i cant find a way to use it. The public void configure(JobConf conf) function that i need to override, i think is deprecated. Well JobConf is deprecated for sure. All the DistributedCache tutorials use the deprecated way to. What can i do? Is there another configure function that i can override??

These are the very first lines of my map function:

```
     Configuration conf = new Configuration();          //load the MFile
     FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
     Path inFile = new Path("planet/MFile");       
     FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(inFile);
     DecisionTree dtree=new DecisionTree().loadTree(in);
```

I want to cache that MFile so that my map function doesn't need to look it over and over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jobconf` was deprecated in `0.20.`x but in `1.0.0` it is not! :-) (as of writing this)

To your question, there are two ways to run map reduce jobs in java, one is by using (`extending`) classes in `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` package and other is by `implementing` classes in `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` package (or the other way round ).

Not sure which one you are using, if you don't have a `configure` method to override, you will get a `setup` method to override.

```
@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

This is similar to configure and should help you.

You get a `setup` method to `override` when you `extend Mapper class` in `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` package.

Comment: Ok i will try this now and tell you the results. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Well i did it, i think. I followed Ravi Bhatt tips and i wrote this :

```
  @Override
  protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {      
      FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
      URI files[]=DistributedCache.getCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
      Path path = new Path(files[0].toString());
      in = fs.open(path);
      dtree=new DecisionTree().loadTree(in);                 
  }
```

Inside my main method i do this, to add it in the cache:

```
  DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(args[0]+"/"+"MFile"), conf);
  Job job = new Job(conf, "MR phase one");
```

I am able to retrieve the file i need with this way, but cant tell yet if it works 100%. Is there any way to test it? Thanks.

Comment: Ok i take that back. It surely works. It runs like the devil. And moreover, i dont have any too many files open problems i used to have.. Hooooraayy